# Find how many minutes old a file is

Tags: php, report

First of all, I know I am not supposed to as "code sample" here. Sadly, I am not a programmer and I have a situation where I need to update a line in a report to present to the customer, but I do not know how to do it.

I have access to PHP file report.php. In the same server and folder as report.php there is a file called report.csv. When report.php is loaded in browser, I want to show one line which will say:

`Report.cvs is X minutes old` that is all.

If the report is 10 days old, then also I can show the age in minutes. I dont need any complicated `X days, Y hours, Z mins` etc.

I am worried i might break something in server if I try to add myself since I am not programmer. Is there anyone who can show me what I need to add to report.php to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.fstat.php you might find that `filectime ( string $filename )` may be useful.

Now if the file is consistently updated by users you may find that storing the creation/upload time in a Database like SQL/sqlite may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so basically you need to get the time when the file was last modified, subtract it from the current time, convert the result to minutes and voilà.

Here's what that should look like:

```
$file = ''; // --- Path to the file

$filetime = filemtime($file); // --- File time

$now = time(); // --- Current Time
$fileAge = round(($now - $filetime)/60); // --- Subtract file time from current time, divide by 60 for the minutes and round the result.

echo basename($file).' is '.$fileAge.' minutes old.';
```

Comment: Thank you Blaise, I will check this!